# How to Enable LongCLicks on my ListView?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to enable Long Clicks in my app and I can't get it to compile.  I looked at the examples from previous questions here, but I can't get any of them to compile.  My main activity is declared as:

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
public class LinearLayoutDemo extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener {
```

In the onCreate() method, I put this:

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
```

And for my ListView (myLV), I did this:

```
myLV1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setOnItemLongClickListener() called for myLV");
        return(true);
    }
});
```

I think the above must be wrong, but I don't know why.  The compiler error is

```
LinearLayoutDemo.java:45: com.commonsware.android.linearpct.LinearLayoutDemo is not abstract and does not override abstract method onItemLongClick(android.widget.AdapterView<?>,android.view.View,int,long) in android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener
[javac] public class LinearLayoutDemo extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener {

LinearLayoutDemo.java:287: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class OnItemLongClickListener
[javac] location: class android.view.View
[javac]         myLV1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new View.OnItemLongClickListener() {
[javac]                                                  ^
```

*********************** *UPDATE* ***********************

I got rid of OnItemLongClickListener in the ListActivity class definition.  I also got rid of this

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
```

Then I added this code and it worked ( I don't know why):

```
myLV1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemLongClick() for LV1");
        return true;
    }
});
```

It seems pretty simple, so I'm sticking with it, unless someone can tell me I shouldn't do it like this.

******************** EDIT **************************

Okay, I have the Long Clicks working.  How can I tell which item I long-clicked?  I had assumed that myLV1.getCheckedItemPosition() would work, but it doesn't.

Nevermind, it's in 'position' parameter to onItemLongClick().

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing here is practicly setting the onLongClickListener twice:

**1.** `getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(this);`

here you set the `Activity` to be the Listener as it implements the `onLongClickListener` interface.

**2.** `myLV1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener() {....`

Here you are creating a new `onItemClickListener` and trying to apply it again to the list.
remove this part from your activity code.

and add unimplemented method:

`onLongClick` that should be in your `Activity` as soon as you activity trying to implement `onLongClickListener`

In this method you can specify what are the actions in case of a long click.

**UPDATE:**

[image]

1. Right click on the error.
2. Add unimplemented methods.

This will add you this code to the class:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

in it define your action for Long click.

Comment: How  can I tell which item was LongClicked?  myLV1.getCheckedItemPosition() doesn't tell me.

Comment: Nevermind, it's in 'position' parameter to onItemLongClick().

Comment: when you set your Activity to implement onLongClickListener you notice that this activity has an error next to it, clicking on the error will urge you to add an override method, see updated answer in a second.

Answer (score 1):

You can do basically two things:

1. Remove the line `getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(this);` since you didn't implemented/overrided the onItemLongClick method of AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener
2. In myLV1.setOnItemLongClickListener you must create a instance of AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener and not the View.OnItemLongClickListener

Comment: I tried the above two things.  I still get the compiler errors: is not abstract and does not override abstract method onItemLongClick.  I don't know what that means.  I also get an error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype.

Comment: The compiler error says that you need to implement onItemLongClick inside your new instance of AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener passed to myLV1.setOnItemLongClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create a context-menu on long-clicking a ListView-Item?

If so the easiest way to achieve this is by using `registerForContextMenu(findViewById(android.R.id.list));` inside your `onCreate`-method.

Then you have to override the methods `onCreateContextMenu` and `onContextItemSelected` like so:

**onCreateContextMenu**

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_context_layout, menu);
}
```

**onContextItemSelected**

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.my_item1:
            doSomething();
            return true;
        case R.id.my_item2:
            doSomething();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the difference between the context-menu on long-clicking a ListView-Item?  I have a ListView and I want to create a CallBack that executes some Java code when I long-click an item.  For now, that java code can be a simple Log.d() call.

Comment: Ok, then my answer is not what you are searching for. My answer provides a menu with selectable things like "edit" or "delete" on long click but that's not what you want to achieve.
I would recommend going with Emil Adz' solution because he points you to adding the unimplemented methods!