# OnItemLongClickListener is undefined

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I use this library: [chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) .

Here is my piece of code:

```
pullToRefreshView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_listview);

ArrayList<String> myStringArray1 =  new ArrayList<String>();
myStringArray1.add("something 1");
myStringArray1.add("something 2");
myStringArray1.add("something 3");
myStringArray1.add("something 4");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myStringArray1);


pullToRefreshView.setAdapter(adapter);

pullToRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
            // Do work to refresh the list here.
            Log.e("myLogs", "Refresh");  
        }           
    });
```

And when I try to make a

```
MyPullToRefreshListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
        View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
  }
);
```

I have an error:

```
The method setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type MyPullToRefreshListView
```

Can I somehow manage this situation?

**EDIT 1:**

Here is my MyPullToRefreshListView class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;

import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView;

public class MyPullToRefreshListView extends PullToRefreshListView {


    public MyPullToRefreshListView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyPullToRefreshListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.listViewStyle);
    }

    public MyPullToRefreshListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(new ContextWrapperEdgeEffect(context), attrs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare `MyPullToRefreshListView`? Is this a class or a variable? If the later, you should change the name to start with a lower case letter as this is the accepted Java convention.

Comment: It's a class, and come from com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView from library.

Comment: What @Code-Apprentice asked: is `setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener)` a static method? Because, currently, that's what it looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow this answer : [How to Enable LongCLicks on my ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862431/how-to-enable-longclicks-on-my-listview) , its really well written ...

Your problem is probably that you implement bad OnItemLongClickListener. Before following steps above, try changing

```
new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){}
```

to

```
new View.OnItemLongClickListener(){}
```

---

**//EDIT:** Accorthing to [this source](https://code.google.com/p/teamthird-oot/source/browse/oot_client_team3/src/oot/fragment/HomeFragment.java?spec=svn213&r=213), you need to implement it like:

```
//mPullRefreshListView.setOn
mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView()
  .setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
        View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("test", "item long cliked");
            initiatePopupWindow(arg1, arg1.getTop(), arg1.getHeight());
            return false;
        }
  });
```

So the key is to call **.getRefreshableView()**

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, it did not worked. I think that the problem is in PullToRefreshListView fnd so on up in hierarchy, where the OnItemLongClickListener is not defined.

Comment: Yeeeeees, the edit area contents the right answer. Thank you :-)